# How to use variable in alias termux?

Tags: terminal, bash, alias

my alias for opening Google is 
is like this 
`alias g="termux-open-url https://google.com"`

for search url  look like this
`http://google.com/search?q=what+I+search`

I wanted that if I write
 `g what I search`
it will open me to Google with definite result .
I had tried a lot with $ but can't get success .Someone please help.

Comment: Don’t use an alias; it can’t  do variable expansion.   Use a function instead.

Comment: How do you get from `what I search` to `?q=what+I+search` currently, or more generally to a search string which works for special characters? https://askubuntu.com/questions/53770/how-can-i-encode-and-decode-percent-encoded-strings-on-the-command-line might help.

Comment: ***It is not possible to use variable*** but the  my motive can be achieved by using
```g() {       termux-open-url https://www.google.com/search?q="$1"+"$2"+"$3"+"$4"+"$5"+"$6"+"$7"
      }```just add in `bash.bashrc` file and if we ever type _g hi_ it will will open chrome by search result hi